# Nested array in a SQL query

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, nested

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm struggling with an SQL Query.

I want, that the purchased articles (article_id) are grouped in an array, so they are connected to the date column. For a further process, they might be combined ( so date x is combined with articles_id [A,B,C])

To make it clearer I want to show what I've done below..

Starting point is this example table:

| Date | Customer_id | article_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | A |
| 123 | 1 | C |
| 125 | 1 | B |
| 124 | 2 | A |
| 126 | 2 | C |

With

```
SELECT 
customer_id,
array_agg(UNIX_SECONDS(Date)) AS Date,
STRING_AGG(((CAST(article_id AS STRING)))) AS article_id
FROM table
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

I managed to transform the table to

| Customer_id | date | article_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [123, 125] | A, B, C |
| 2 | [124, 126] | A, C |

No finally the question!

is it possible

To get to :

| Customer_id | date | article_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [123, 125] | [[A, C], [B]] |
| 2 | [124, 126] | [[A], [C]] |

And if so, how?

I'm thankful for every piece of advice or wording to continue my search. And of cause thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this? Aggregate twice, first for customer_id, date_time. Then simply for customer_id. (Sorry I've called the date column to date_time)

```
with input as (
select 123 date_time, 1 customer_id, 'A' article_id
UNION ALL
select 123 date_time, 1 customer_id, 'C' article_id
UNION ALL
select 125 date_time, 1 customer_id, 'B' article_id
UNION ALL
select 124 date_time, 2 customer_id, 'A' article_id
UNION ALL
select 126 date_time, 2 customer_id, 'C' article_id)


select customer_id, array_agg(distinct date_time) date_time, array_agg(STRUCT(article_id)) article_id from (
   select customer_id,date_time, array_agg(article_id) article_id from input
   group by customer_id, date_time
) group by customer_id
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is what I wanted, finally :) 

date_time isn't an issue ;) Call it what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in 2 steps.
Step 1, group by customer_id and date, and stringagg your article_id.
That gets you the [A, C] you want for date 123.

Then using that query as that FROM for the outer query, you should be able to get what you're looking for.  (or you could use a WITH clause if you prefer that format)